# How to spec a vector of custom spec'ed maps

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have a spec for a custom map named `::cell`, let's say

```
(s/def ::attr-1 int?)
(s/def ::attr-2 int?)
(s/def ::cell :req-un [::attr-1 ::attr-2])
```

Now I want another spec `::grid` for a custom vector that consists of only these `::cell` maps. As an example, a grid might look like this:

```
(let grid [{:attr-1 11, :attr-2 12} {:attr-1 21 :attr-2 22}])
```

Is it possible to create a spec for this requirement using the specification of `::cell`?

```
(s/def ::grid ???)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tuple`:

```
(s/def ::grid (s/tuple ::cell ::cell ::cell))
```

or `coll-of` specifying the kind and count:

```
(s/coll-of ::cell :kind vector? :count 3)
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of the fact that a spec like `::grid` could be used as the first argument to `s/coll-of`!